# how do I activate a function in my chrome extension each time its tab becomes active

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My background script is collecting data. I want it to update a table on the main page whenever it is in view. Is this possible?

Comment: See here, this seems to be close to what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need permission to access the tab data.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Then you can use the `onActivated` event.

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(callback)
```

More information here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html